# how can i replace scanf with for loop counter?

Tags: c

I am writing a program in order to count all achilles numbers without the math.h library. In this programm first I calculate powerful numbers after that I calculate GCD of powerful number. If GCD is 1 then the current number is achilles.

My problem is that my program works with `scanf()` but not with for loop counter! What i am doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int i, j, a;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int large;
    int small;
    int rem, gcd, max = 1, min = 1;
    int achilles;

    for (a = 1; a <= MAX; a++) //for loop for counter
    {
        n=a;

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int l = 0;

            if (count == 2)
            {
                while (n % i == 0) // calculate factor and his exponent
                {
                    l++;
                    n = n / i;
                }

                if (l > max) // calculates min and max in order to find GCD
                {
                    max = l;
                }
                if (l < min)
                {
                    min = l;
                }
            }

            large = max;
            small = min;
            while (small) { // While small is not 0
                            // Calculates GCD
                rem = large % small;
                large = small;
                small = rem;
            }
            gcd = large;
            // printf("GCD(%d,%d)= %d", large, small, gcd);
        }
        if (gcd == 1) {
            achilles = n;
            // printf("%d\n", achilles);
        }
        // printf("GCD(%d,%d)= %d", max, min, gcd);
        printf("%d\n", achilles);
    }   
}
```

The programm before editing with the for loop is the following!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int i, j, a;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int large;
    int small;
    int rem, gcd, max = 1, min = 1;
    int achilles;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d = ",n);

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int l = 0;

            if (count == 2)
            {
                while (n % i == 0) // calculate factor and his exponent
                {
                    l++;
                    n = n / i;
                }

                if (l > max) // calculates min and max in order to find GCD
                {
                    max = l;
                }
                if (l < min)
                {
                    min = l;
                }
            }

            large = max;
            small = min;
            while (small) { // While small is not 0
                            // Calculates GCD
                rem = large % small;
                large = small;
                small = rem;
            }
            gcd = large;
            // printf("GCD(%d,%d)= %d", large, small, gcd);
        }
        /*if (gcd == 1) {
            achilles = n;
            // printf("%d\n", achilles);
        }*/
        printf("GCD(%d,%d)= %d", max, min, gcd);
        //printf("%d\n", achilles);
}
```

Comment: `int max=1,min=1;` is strange with the same value.  I'd expect `int max=INT_MIN,min=INT_MAX;` or the like

Comment: Where exactly is `scanf()` that you like to replace with the loop counter value?

Comment: I replaced it with for (a = 1; a <= MAX; a++)  ! :@

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with the `for` loop counter, what you might can do with the `scanf()`-function? I do not understand your relation between those two.

Comment: i edit the post and i upload the code before edit!

Comment: Similar to [How can i modify my code to make it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59128611/2410359)