# How can i modify my code to make it work?

Tags: c

Hello i try to make a university exercise that calculate the GCD without math.h library! I have write this code but i can't understand why my code doesn't get in if statement of (min, max) calculation!Seems that the code doesn't give the results that i want an if statement condition! I have try everything! Please any idea what's going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int i, j, a;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int large;
    int small;
    int rem, gcd;
    int max=INT_MIN,min=INT_MAX;
    int achilles;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d = ",n);

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int l = 0;

            if (count == 2)
            {
                int expo;
                while (n % i == 0) // calculate factor and his exponent
                {
                    l++;
                    n = n / i;
                }
                expo=l;

                if (expo > max) // calculates min and max in order to find GCD
                {
                    max = expo;
                    large = max;
                }
                if (expo < max)
                {
                    min = expo;
                    small = min;
                }
            }

            //large = max;
            //small = min;
            while (small) { // While small is not 0
                            // Calculates GCD
                rem = large % small;
                large = small;
                small = rem;
            }
            //gcd = large;
            // printf("GCD(%d,%d)= %d", large, small, gcd);
        }
        gcd = large;
        printf("GCD(%d,%d)= %d", large, small, gcd);

}
```

Comment: It looks like a good time to learn how to use a debugger to step through you code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Looks like this `expo < max` want to be `expo < min`.

Comment: One thing you need to check though is what happens when `expo == max`. And what value `large` will have is `expo < max` is true, or what value `small` will have if `expo > max`.

Comment: GCD is calculated for two numbers, I can only see you reading one. Are we both thinking of Greatest Comon Denominator?

Comment: Are you trying to find highest factor ?

Comment: Consider editing the question: proper title. `How can i modify my code to make it work` does not help readers decide if they can help, based on the topic. Also proper question: `Whats going on ?` is not very specific.

Comment: Looks similar to OP's recent and still open  https://stackoverflow.com/q/59127411/2410359 .  Why 2 post on essentially the same code?

Comment: Yes i am trying to find Greatest Common Factor!